# Are bits (0/1) named "characters" anywhere in the literature?

Tags: terminology

I know that each character ("in the macro level") is comprised of at least two bits ("in the micro level").

But are these bits of this "micro, electrical-logical level" have been considered "characters" by themselves anywhere in the literature and would it make any sense to define them as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, a name is just a means for communication.  You can use any terms and definitions you want as long as you and your audience both agree on the meaning of them and as long as it doesn't cause confusion.

In practice, no, bits are not characters.  The word "character" has an accepted definition and most people would probably find it confusing if you used the word "character" to refer to a single bit.

Comment: OTOH, parser guys call something like {0, 1} an "alphabet" and things constructed from such alphabets according to a grammar "sentences", so … :-D Joking aside, a common way to refer to those would be "symbols".